# How can I see standard output of next.js application in amplify hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-amplify

I would like to understand why my next.js application is not working as expected after deploying to amplify hosting, while it works well on my computer. But currently I don't see the console.error and console.log output from the hosting. I've spent weeks of time guessing and trying what is wrong and I haven't find a solution with logs, can't understand how to set up them or where to find.

Using Monitoring documentation I can see only logs with incoming requests and responses, but not what is printed to console.

Also I found some instructions how to setup logging to CloudWatch with custom functions. But I don't see it very useful. Obviously I would like to see everything my backend types to console, not only what I've sent myself after a lot of configuring.

I speak at least about the backend logs.